# iMessage - detect when an MSMessage is tapped

Tags: ios, imessage, msmessage

I'm developing an iMessage extension where there is a view to browse content. After selecting one, it sends as an MSMessage. I'm trying to display an image preview when the user taps on the MSMessage bubble after it's sent.

I was hoping to use `func didSelect(MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation)` to detect the tap, but this method only gets called when the selectedMessage *changes*. This will work the first time, but if the user selects the same message again, I haven't found a way to distinguish the message select from a tap on the "show expanded view" button.

Can anyone think of a workaround for this?

Comment: Have you found the solution between "tap" and "show expanded view" button?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I think it's impossible right now. Hopefully Apple changes this behavior

Comment: Check Coub app. They are successfully differentiating. Wondering how they are doing so.

Comment: You can use a `MSMessageLiveLayout` for your layout and add a tap gesture to the view. This is for iOS 11 only.